# what's the rationale behind setting margin to @line-height-computed / 2 in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm reading [an article about `Vertical Rhythm`](http://24ways.org/2006/compose-to-a-vertical-rhythm/) which promotes the idea of vertically aligning elements according to `rhythmic unit`. I assumed that perhaps bootstrap's team tries to adhere to that principle when designing their typography styles. But it doesn't seem to be so. For example, having the following presets:

```
@font-size-base:          14px;
@line-height-base:        1.428571429; // 20/14
@line-height-computed:    floor((@font-size-base * @line-height-base)); // ~20px

body {
  font-size: @font-size-base;
  line-height: @line-height-base;
}
```

in order to adhere to `rhytmic unit` of `20px (@font-size-base * @line-height-base)` the margin of a paragraph should be `20px (@line-height-computed)`, where in bootstrap it's currently set as `10px (@line-height-computed / 2)`.

So what's the idea behind the typography settings in bootstrap (it doesn't seem to be the `Vertical Rhythm`) ?

PS. Any way I can ask this question to bootstrap's team?

Comment: There is a couple threads about this and @mdo "Yeah, I've been feeling the pain on this one as well. We added the top margins in v3, I think. I override these quite often." Yes, you are correct, it should be 20px. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11601 and https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1943#issuecomment-29862005

Comment: Got you, thanks! Do you think I should override the styles to make them consistent with Vertical Rhythm approach? Or should I work with these values until v4 of Bootstrap comes about?

Comment: I make better looking typography but watch out for components and vertical spacing (when the site is stacked). See they have top and bottom margins on their h6-h1, p, ul, ol, form, table, etc., and so -- assuming those elements are in your columns and you haven't fiddled with the margins -- when the design stacks there will be some vertical space, if you remove them, the space below images but before a title, for example, will be gone. Putting margin or padding on the top or the bottom of rows or columns also gives trouble when nested and in forms

Comment: I tried the approach offered in the [article](http://csswizardry.com/2012/06/single-direction-margin-declarations/) mentioned in the first post your specified in your comments. It suggests using equal `margin-top`, while the approach described in the [article](http://24ways.org/2006/compose-to-a-vertical-rhythm/) I mentioned in the question entails variable `margin-top` depending on the font-size of the element. Which one do you think is better? Which is going to be implemented in v4 of bootstrap? Any thoughts?

Comment: Not a clue what @mdo will do with v4. Top and bottom margins annoy me more than they help me. Consistent bottom margins stack nicely. See in 2 columns, if you have a top margin on the text element, the image will not align unless you put that image, in yet another wrapper, that has the same margin or all your images have that margin which will become an override on thumbs and all kinds of other issues

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll leave it as it is for now.